# jQuery to disable/enable textarea depending on which radio button is selected inside of loop

Tags: jquery

I have the following form fields. If the radio button `(travel_yes/no_##)` is changed from `No` to `Yes`, then the following textarea `(travelDetails_#)` should become enabled.  If they change it back to No, then the textarea should be disabled again.  I'd like to stay away from using `.next()` or `.find()` for performance since I know my ID values will be unique (also the location of the textarea fields may change).

**UPDATED:  RADIO BUTTONS SHOULD BE GROUPS PER SET, NOT ALL TOGETHER**

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="travel1" data-travelNumber="1" id="travel_yes_1" value="Yes" tabindex="25" >
        Yes 
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input name="travel1" type="radio" data-travelNumber="1" id="travel_no_1" value="No" tabindex="26" checked >
        No
    </label>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <textarea name="travelDetails" id="travelDetails_1" ></textarea>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="travel2" data-travelNumber="2" id="travel_yes_2" value="Yes" tabindex="25" >
        Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input name="travel2" type="radio" data-travelNumber="2" id="travel_no_2" value="No" tabindex="26" checked >
        No
    </label>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <textarea name="travelDetails" id="travelDetails_2"></textarea>
</div>


<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="travel3" data-travelNumber="3" id="travel_yes_3" value="Yes" tabindex="25" >
        Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input name="travel3" type="radio" data-travelNumber="3" id="travel_no_3" value="No" tabindex="26" checked >
        No
    </label>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <textarea name="travelDetails" id="travelDetails_3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code that ISN'T working.

```
$("[data-travelNumber]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), limit = +$(this).data("travelNumber");
    $("input:radio[name=travel]:checked").live('click',function(){
        if ( $(this).val() === 'Yes' )
            $('#travelDetails_' + limit).removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $('#travelDetails_' + limit).attr("disabled", "enabled");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It is always better NOT to use custom HTML attributes, it restricts code validation and may not work properly in all browsers.

Comment: This is for a back-end product and the client's browser supports it.  But that is good info for someone else who might come across this, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this taking the number from the id to find the appropriate textarea

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    var $p = $(this).closest('.controls');
    var $checked = $p.find(':checked');
    $('#travelDetails_' + this.id.slice(-1)).prop('disabled',$checked.val() == 'No');   
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hnwYM/

or change it to this if you ever have numbers over 9

```
$('#travelDetails_' + this.id.slice(-1))
```

to

```
$('#travelDetails_' + this.id.split('_')[2])
```

Or you can use your data attr

```
$('#travelDetails_' + $(this).attr('data-travelNumber'))
```

You can use the same methodology to stop from traversing the dom

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    var num = $(this).attr('data-travelNumber');
    var $checked = $('input[id$=_' + num + ']:checked');
    $('#travelDetails_' + num).prop('disabled',$checked.val() == 'No');   
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U9Ywe/

Comment: I dind't catch that originally.  Sorry about that and thanks for catching the radio names.

Comment: Checking out solution... This is the approach I was aiming for myself.

Comment: Ack, I'm trying to stay away from traversing the DOM since I'm not 100% sure of the location of the textarea box.  This is still a draft for the client and they may want it somewhere else.

Comment: I'll re-evaluate your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've created something in JsFiddle that does the trick for you. I fixed the radio buttons group names because they had all the same name.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // disable all the textarea on start
    $("textarea").attr("disabled", true);

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
        id = id[id.length-1];

        // or use your data-travelNumber attribute
        // id = $(this).data('travelNumber');

        $("#travelDetails_" + id).attr("disabled", !($(this).val() == "Yes"));
    });
});​
```

Here is the example: [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjr3T/3/)

Comment: This solution also worked and was a little easier for me to read (based on my level of experience in using jQuery) since I haven't studied the .prop() function yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dPaCT/1/)**

```
$("input:radio[name^=travel]").live('click', function() {

    idparts = this.id.split('_');
    textArea = document.getElementById('travelDetails_' + idparts[idparts.length - 1]);

    if (this.value === 'Yes')
       textArea.disabled = true;
    else 
        textArea.disabled = false;
});​
```

Comment: Good answer but he stated `I'd like to stay away from using .next() or .find() for performance`

Comment: Also, the radio buttons should be independent, not a group.

Comment: @dlackey but they all have the same name.. which groups them

Comment: Half the code: `$(this).closest('.controls').next('.controls').find('textarea').attr('disabled', $(this).val() === 'Yes');`

Comment: I used the javascript to make ids to increase performance have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[data-travelNumber]").click(function(){
    var txt = $("#travelDetails_" + $(this).attr("data-travelNumber"));
    if($(this).val() === "Yes")
        txt.removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        txt.attr("disabled", "disabled");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$("input:radio[name=travel]").live('click', function() {
    $('travelDetails_' + $(this).data("travelNumber")).attr('disabled', $(this).val() === 'Yes');
});
```

When a radio button is clicked, get it's `travelNumber`, and enable or disable the textarea with `id='travelDetails_'+travelNumber`, depending on the number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$("input:radio[name=travel]").live('click', function() {
    f = $(this).attr("id").search("yes");
    i = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[2];

    if(f != -1) {
        $("#travelDetails_" + i).removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $("#travelDetails_" + i).attr("disabled", "true");
    }
});
```