# Dynamic form field validation using jquery AND Rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This question is an extension of my SO question:

[jQuery to disable/enable textarea depending on which radio button is selected inside of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992834/jquery-to-disable-enable-textarea-depending-on-which-radio-button-is-selected-in#13993147)

I'm using the jQuery bassistance validation plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

The validation rule I'm trying to create is if a radio button equals 'yes', then make the textarea a required field.  My ID's and form field names for the radio and textarea boxes are dynamic but begin with the same word so I can use `name^='travel'`

**HTML**
**UPDATED**

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="travel_1" data-travelNumber="1" id="travel_yes_1" value="Yes" tabindex="25" >
        Yes </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input name="travel_1" type="radio" data-travelNumber="1" id="travel_no_1" value="No" tabindex="26" checked >
        No </label>
</div>
<div class="controls" id="Answer_travel_yes_1">
    <textarea name="travelDetails_1" id="travelDetails_1" ></textarea>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="travel_2" data-travelNumber="2" id="travel_yes_2" value="Yes" tabindex="25" >
        Yes </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input name="travel_2" type="radio" data-travelNumber="2" id="travel_no_2" value="No" tabindex="26" checked >
        No </label>
</div>
<div class="controls" id="Answer_travel_yes_2">
    <textarea name="travelDetails_2" id="travelDetails_2"></textarea>
</div>


<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="travel_3" data-travelNumber="3" id="travel_yes_3" value="Yes" tabindex="25" >
        Yes </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input name="travel_3" type="radio" data-travelNumber="3" id="travel_no_3" value="No" tabindex="26" checked >
        No </label>
</div>
<div class="controls" id="Answer_travel_yes_3">
    <textarea name="travelDetails_3" id="travelDetails_3"></textarea>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//  I use this to hide/show the travelDetails textarea (show on yes, hide on no)
$('input:radio[name^="travel"]:checked').live('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    id = id[id.length-1];
    $("#travelDetails_" + id).attr("disabled", !($(this).val() == "Yes"));
    if ( $(this).val() == 'Yes' ) 
        $('#Answer_travel_yes_' + id).slideDown();
    else
        $('#Answer_travel_yes_' + id).slideUp();
});


$("#TravelForm").validate({
        rules:{
            whatgoeshere:{
                    required: function(){
                        if ( $("input:radio[name^=travel]:checked").val() == "Yes" ){
                            //  make travel
                            true
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('false');
                            true
                        }
          },
                    minlength: 10   // needs to have at least 10 characters entered (if the corresponding radio is Yes
            }
        },
        messages:{
            whatgoeshere:{
                required:"Please enter your travel details",
                minlength:"Please enter at least 10 characters"
            }
        },
        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            //  $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have not really asked a question or explained very much about what you've already tried, what part is working, or what you still need help doing.  You should also supplement this question with a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: I'm still somewhat unclear about what you're trying to do, but my answer should contain enough methods & documentation that shows how you can fix your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic answer which you can apply into your code...

---

I am fairly certain you cannot use a function inside the `rules` option.  [As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), `rules:` need to be "key/value pairs", unless using the `depends` property.

```
rules: {
    mytextarea: {
        minlength: 10,
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $("#myradio:checked")
            }
        }
    }
},
messages: {
    mytextarea: {
        required: "Please enter your travel details",
        minlength: "Please enter at least 10 characters"
    }
}
```

`mytextarea` would be the `value` of the `name` attribute of your `textarea`.

```
<textarea name="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

---

**Alternatively...**

Apply jQuery `.validate()` rules dynamically.

First initialize your `.validate()` plugin with options:

```
$('form').validate({
    // your options, leave out the rule in question
});
```

Create a rules array (note the slightly different format when using `messages`):

```
var myrule = {
    required: true,
    minlength: 10,
    messages: {
        required: "Please enter your travel details",
        minlength: "Please enter at least 10 characters"
    }
}
```

Then within your conditional, target the `textarea` as required:

```
if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
    $('[name^="travel"]').rules('add', myrule);
} else {
    $('[name^="travel"]').rules('remove', myrule);
}
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules

---

BTW, [`.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Regarding the .live(), old habits die hard.  I keep forgetting about that one.  I found a blog post about the function inside of the rule.  If I can find it again, I'll post it here as an addendum.  That said, I completely follow what you are saying so I'm go your route instead.  Thank you!

Comment: @dlackey, I'm glad I could help.  Keep in mind that you'll find many blog posts about using the `.validate()` plugin in ways that it was not intended as per official documentation.  That being said, some of these things are perfectly valid methods, and some are just so verbose & obtuse, that the plugin just acts weird.  So "buyer beware".   (you can also [search my profile for dozens of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A594235+%5Bjquery-validate%5D&submit=search) related to `.validate` plugin)

Comment: That is a lot of answers.  I think someone knows their stuff!  :D